# why i am getting the same title of my like button of facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have two pages (case_1.html,blog_1.html) and onther two page containing facebook like it button for both page(case.html,blog.html) . When i like case_1.html then i get the title of like button is same as i like the blog_1.html.

I have also used open graph tag in case_1.html but i get the same title of blog_1.html.

Please help me.
my code for case_1.html is

```
  <title>Case Study </title>
  <meta property="og:title" content="Case Study " />
   <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://mywebsites.com/case_1.html" />
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsites.com/img/case_study/Arvind.JPG" />
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="mywebsites.com" />
 <meta property="fb:app_id" content="my_id" />
```

and i use following code for like it on case.html juse below  tag

```
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://mywebsites.com/case_1.html" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="arial"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you made a copy of `blog_1.html` and entered the link on facebook **before** you updated the meta data? Facebook is caching the meta information a very long time. You can call the [facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test your data. Also the cache is cleared when you enter a url in the debugger. So after you entered the url and everything is correct, normal sharing should work, too.

Comment: Thank you for your help .but how to change my description of page.

Comment: You have to add `<meta property="og:description " content="Here you go" />`. See also http://ogp.me/ for all possible properties.